# Can we stop Flutter plugin loading if not use in final build

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

Seems if a plugin package is included in pubspec.yaml, it will be included in build even not use.

Take my sample project https://github.com/J-Siu/flutter_scroll as example, `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
name: flutter_scroll
description: A new Flutter project.
version: 1.0.0+1
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.17.6 <3.0.0"
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  google_sign_in: ^5.4.1
dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_lints: ^2.0.0
flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

`google_sign_in` is a plugin but not imported in any of the source code and there is no dependency using it.

However if you go to the demo page: https://j-siu.github.io/app/flutter_scroll/#/ , open browser inspector -> network, reload the page, you will see `https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js` is loaded. That is done by `google_sign_in` initialization.

Question: Other than removing it from pubspec.yaml, is there a way to exclude plugin from final build if it is not imported in source and other dependency?

PS: You can experiment with a plain starting project:

1. flutter create --platforms web my_testing
2. cd my_testing
3. flutter pub add google_sign_in
4. flutter run (should open chrome)
5. check inspector -> network with reload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, i dont think its possible to not use a package thats defined in pubspec during build. You could take a look at packages like

[Dependency validator](https://pub.dev/packages/dependency_validator)

Where you get to know which packages arent used at all and remove them easily.

Comment: That is what I am afraid of. It got my attention as I am developing a sign-in package that cover extension/app/web, with a common class interface. But the extension keep loading the plugin though it is not imported in final code. Will wait a few days and see what other say, and may open an issue with the official dart repo.